# Como faço para abrir um arquivo de um diretório específico em .PDF no Visual Basic 6?

Tags: c#, framework, script, visual-basic-6

Criei uma aplicação a qual salva arquivos em um diretório específico.
O que eu gostaria é de ao clicar um botão, eu consiga abrir este arquivo .pdf.

Comment: Se é VB porquê a tag C#?

Comment: Por que programo nas duas linguagens. Se existir uma solução em C#  talvez possa transcrever para vb6

Comment: Então sugiro que retire a referência ao VB do título da pergunta e coloque essa informação no corpo.

Answer (score 2):

C# e WindowsForms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\" ;
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf" ;

    if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    }
}
```

O código acima abre, quando o botão for clicado, um dialog onde pode ser selecionado um arquivo pdf.
O arquivo será aberto pela aplicação associada à extensão `.pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

Ao arrastar um controle do tipo OpenFileDialog, basta ir ao arquivo 'designer'e definir as propriedades, conforme a resposta anterior.

Se precisarem colocar mais de uma opção na propriedade 'Filter':

```
openFileDialog1.Filter =  "Texto|*.txt;*.dat;*.csv|"   + _
                          "imagem|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif|" + _
                          "audio|*.mp3;*.aac;*.wma|"   + _
                          "planilha Excel|*.xls|"      + _
                          "Todos os arquivos|*.*"
```

Observação: a propriedade 'Filter' recebe apenas uma string. Só quebrei a linha para facilitar a leitura.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Declarepara Executar
Public Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long


'Sub para Executar
Sub subExecuta(strPath As String)
    ShellExecute 0, "Open", strPath, "", "", vbNormalFocus
End Sub


'Executa
call subExecuta(App.Path & "\file.pdf")
```